# Firebase: update value in array object

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm using Firebase DataBase in my application.
Below is my Collection data

```
Object {
  "buyer": Object {
    "firstName": "firstname",
    "lastName": "lastName",
    "phoneNumber": "9876543210",
  },
  "buyerId": "TfHemJat3L3kkz0t3qDn",
  "orderDate": "Sat May 29 18:55:47 2021",
  "orderDetails": Array [
    Object {
      "itemId": "3iPDW2OJePJBCuR6xA09",
      "status": "Pending",
    },
    Object {
      "itemId": "jDJDHaBLI2kQ4reaaWI8",
      "status": "Pending",
    },
  ],
  "orderId": "t20212941855550",
}
```

I want to update the **Status** from **Pending** to **Accepted** where only
**ItemId == "3iPDW2OJePJBCuR6xA09"**.

I don't know how to update, Can you please suggest the solution to the same.

Thank in Advance.

Comment: Firebase has several different products - are you using the Realtime Database or Firestore? The solution will be very different based on that. If it's Firestore, that'a a great section on how to [Update Elements In An Array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) right in the getting  started guide. Also, it's best practice to include the code you've attempted. We are not a code-writing service so we want see where your stuck. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the update function predefined in the firebase library and inside that function pass the argument and variable in which you want to update with the values in the same format as it was created in the database also vote if it works